# In C, my execl function works but when trying to use execlp I am getting no print from the file

Tags: c, fork, exec

I have created a hw.c file that is a simple print function of "Hello World\n". I have compiled it and named it hw. the first fork does work and prints out "Hellow World" like I want it to. But the execlp function in the second fork does not. It simply prints out nothing. It will compile fine but when i execute the program nothing is printed to the user. I am under the impression that I just need to give the exact file name in execlp and then give the name again in order for it to work. Any help with pushing me in the right direction would be great, I have commented out the first fork and ran it still nothing so I know it has to be the execlp not the execl.

```
//exec commands
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

void  main( void )
{
    pid_t  pid;
    pid_t  pid2;
    int status;


    pid = fork();  // creates a new process
    if (pid == 0)
    {

      execl("/home/student/xsperopoulos/hw", "hw", NULL ) ;

    } else
      {

        int ret = wait ( &status);

      }

    pid2 = fork();  // creates a new process
    if (pid2 == 0)
    {

      execlp("hw", "hw",NULL);

    } else
      {

        int ret = wait(&status);

      }


}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value from `execlp` and report if there's an error. Otherwise, you have no way to know if it succeeded or not. My bet is there is no executable named `hw` in the path.

Comment: how would i check the return value? When I run the execlp by itself after compiling it successfully, it prints nothing.

Comment: nevermind, im not the brightest, I had to do execlp("./hw",hw",NULL); for it to work

Comment: @XavierSperopoulos read the documentation of execlp. It returns an integer depending on success or error: " `Return Value:
The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.`"